# How to Write " - 0 " in Excel Cell

Tags: excel-formula

I am writing "-0" in excel cell i.e Discharge of liquid has "0" magnitude but "Anticlockwise" direction. Is there any way that I can write "-0" in a cell ? Thanks

Comment: Type `'-0` in the cell and it will be formatted as text

Comment: or format the whole column text and then it will not convert it to a number.

Comment: @Lisa Is it possible If I multiply '-0 with any positive number then it given negative number ?

Comment: @ScottCraner  Is it possible If I multiply '-0 with any positive number then it given negative number ?

Comment: No, excel will return `0` not matter what.

Comment: Perhaps you should contrive a way of representing your values in another way, i.e. as 2 values in 2 columns instead of a composite that disobeys arithmetical rules.

Comment: @Bhai What result do you want to achieve? If you want "-0" as a result of multiplying by "-0" then you can write `=IF(A2="-0","-0",A2*B2)`.

Comment: thanks @Lisa  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can but it will be a string, just write:

```
'-0
```

Comment: you don't need single quote as well, just change type of cell from general to text, then type -0